# How to count the result of this bat command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I came up with this command to show all the files inside a directory with a specific size:

```
Get-ChildItem -path Z:\htdocs\zz -recurse | where { $_.Length -eq 2254 }
```

Now I would like to know HOW MANY results were returned... how do I do that?

Using measure I can count but I cant compare it with a number... for example, i would like to compare it to 3, if it is equal to 3 files I would like to do some stuff.

EDIT

I also want to delete the files. I came up with this code but it is not actually deleting the files AND it does not display at the end the amount of files deleted:

```
Get-ChildItem -path Z:\htdocs\zz | where { $_.Length -eq 2254 } | ?{Remove-Item $_.fullname -WhatIf}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Measure-Object` cmdlet can count objects.

```
$objectCount = Get-ChildItem Z:\htdocs\zz -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 2254 } |
  Measure-Object |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

You want the `Count` property of the `Measure-Object` output object.

Comment: great! How do I compare the last result to 1? If it's bigger than 1 I would like to delete all files

Comment: `help about_If`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(Get-ChildItem -path Z:\htdocs\zz -recurse | where { $_.Length -eq 2254 }).Count
```

by putting it in brackets and adding the `$` you "speak" to the result object and can then use the object function `Count`

Comment: It worked, very simple :) But how do I compare the count to 1? If it's bigger than 1 I would like to delete all files with that specific size.

Comment: this is a good read https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-comparison-operators-eq-lt-gt-contains-like-match/ .. in short: `if($(Get-ChildItem -path Z:\htdocs\zz -recurse | where { $_.Length -eq 2254 }).Count
 -gt 1) { delete it }` you may want to store the count in another variable for readability. but I recommend reading the article